# Getting line equation in polar coords from cartesian coords

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have a line equation `y = kx + b` in cartesian coords. I need to get it in polar coords. I know, I should use a Jacobian, but I don't understand how to use it.
Can anybody show a simple example? Thanks

Comment: Let (0,0) be the origin, the  you can substitute $y=r \sin \theta$ and $x=r \cos \theta$

Comment: You should just substitute $x=r\cos\varphi$, $y=r\sin\varphi$ into $y=kx+b$: $r\cos\varphi = kr\sin\varphi + b$. Jacobians needs for volumes (areas).

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Galuza, thanks. So, one question. I have a curve defined on Fourier series. So I want to find an intersection of it and this line. Is it right?:
_rcos(fi) = kr sin(fi) + 1_
_r = r0 + sum (...)     <--- Fourier series_

Comment: @Mike_Device, it's a better way to post new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: In polar coordinates, $(r,\theta)$:

$$x=r\cos \theta, \ y=r\sin \theta$$

Answer (score 0):

you only need to substitute $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$